# cuda error in python flask Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method

Tags: python, flask, pytorch

I have a problem. In flask when i put comennted code in dev i have an error. Code outside dev worked. I don't known why.

Code:

```
import random
import json
import torch
import spacy
import os
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
from .model import NeuralNet
from .nltk_utils import bag_of_words, tokenize

# from asistant_funt import extract_app_name

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
with open('models/friday/intents.json', 'r') as f:
    intents = json.load(f)
FILE = 'models/friday/data.pth'
data = torch.load(FILE)
input_size = data["input_size"]
hidden_size = data["hidden_size"]
output_size = data["output_size"]
all_words = data["all_words"]
tags = data["tags"]
model_state = data["model_state"]
model = NeuralNet(input_size, hidden_size, output_size).to(device)
model.load_state_dict(model_state)
model.eval()
bot_name = 'friday'

# print("Let's chat type 'quit' to exit")
# while True:
#     respons = ''
#     sentence = input("You: ")
#     if sentence == "quit":
#         break
#     message = sentence
#     sentence = tokenize(sentence)
#     X = bag_of_words(sentence, all_words)
#     X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
#     X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)
#
#     output = model(X)
#     _, prdicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)
#
#     tag = tags[prdicted.item()]
#     probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
#     prob = probs[0][prdicted.item()]
#
#     if prob.item() > 0.85:
#         for intent in intents['intents']:
#             if tag == intent["tag"]:
#                 respons = random.choice(intent["responses"])
#                 print(f'{bot_name}: {respons}')
#     else:
#         print(f"{bot_name}: I don't understand...")

def Friday_chat(sentence):
    respons = ''
    message = sentence
    sentence = tokenize(sentence)
    X = bag_of_words(sentence, all_words)
    X = X.reshape(1, X.shape[0])
    X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)
    output = model(X)
    _, predicted = torch.max(output, dim=1)
    tag = tags[predicted.item()]
    probs = torch.softmax(output, dim=1)
    prob = probs[0][predicted.item()]
    if prob.item() > 0.85:
        for intent in intents['intents']:
            if tag == intent["tag"]:
                respons = random.choice(intent["responses"])
                return f'{bot_name}: {respons}'
    else:
        return f"{bot_name}: I don't understand..."

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Blueprint, send_from_directory
import os
import random
import string
import json
from models.friday.chat import Friday_chat


models_routes = Blueprint('models_routes', __name__)
@models_routes.route('/friday', methods=['POST'])

def friday():
    logout_data = request.get_json()
    if 'data' in logout_data:
        data = logout_data['data']
        response = Friday_chat(data)
        print(response)
        return jsonify({'field': response, 'valu': True})
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Brak wymaganych danych'}), 400
```

error:

[2023-11-15 20:29:57,913] ERROR in app: Exception on /friday [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/home/ratt00/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ratt00/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/ratt00/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/ratt00/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/media/ratt00/Nowy/Antek/programowanie/python/echo/host/funtions/models_utils.py", line 17, in friday
    response = Friday_chat(data)
  File "/media/ratt00/Nowy/Antek/programowanie/python/echo/host/models/friday/chat.py", line 69, in Friday_chat
    X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)
  File "/home/ratt00/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 284, in _lazy_init
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Cannot re-initialize CUDA in forked subprocess. To use CUDA with multiprocessing, you must use the 'spawn' start method

127.0.0.1 - - [15/Nov/2023 20:29:57] "POST /friday HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I tried use spawn method but it didn't work because i had more errors. Put spawn method in def didn't work.

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to put:

```
set_start_method('spawn')
```

inside

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
```

Here is a comprehensive discussion in this git link: **https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/40403**

> 1. Use `spawn` method.
> 2. Do not do any GPU operations inside of the Dataset **init** and inside of the main code, move everything into **get_iterm** or **iter**